# How to find out the table involved in deadlock

Tags: sql-server

I use MS SQL Server 2014 for my Java-based web app. I saw a few database-related exceptions in the web log. Each one looks like the following:

Transaction (Process ID 138) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

From the above info, I am not able to see which tables are involved. How can I find out the tables in question based on the above information?

Comment: There's a nice stored procedure that you can download called sp_whoisative.  it'll show you pretty much all the information you're looking for.  It'll show you the query text that's running.  This is what I use to find locked up processes.  I'm sure there are more or better answers. http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/release/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx

Comment: For a slightly more updated version of the `sp_whoisactive`: http://www.whoisactive.com/

Comment: Hello Emuevil and SqlZim, at this moment, I only want to find out which tables got involved in the past deadlocked transactions. Is this script able do that? Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: Maybe you could get more information from the Sql Server logs. In SSMS,  open up Management in the Object Explorer. From there, open up SQL Server Logs and select the Current.

Comment: Jason, thanks for pointing me to this. I checked the place you mentioned, but I am not able to see any error messages.